# Problema no me toma una variable local cuando llamo a una clase

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, cree una clase que tiene un contador y un arreglo booleano, si la posición es par y `true`, suma 1; y si es impar y `false` también sum.

Declaré un arreglo y lo inicialicé como 0, o sea `{}`, luego en el `main` cree el arreglo que utilizo en éste, pero cuando llamo a la clase (`nombre_de_la_clase(arreglo)`) me toma 0 que es como inicialicé el arreglo de la clase donde estaba el contador.

Éste es el código:

```
public class principal {
     public static void main (String [] args) {
    boolean[] array = {true, false, true, false, true, false, true};
    System.out.println (prod(array));
     } 
        public static int prod(boolean [] args) {
        boolean[] arreglo = {};
        int sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<arreglo.length; ++i) {
                   if (i%2<=0) {
            if (arreglo[i]== true) {
                sum++;
               }
             }
            else {
            if (arreglo[i]== false) {
                sum++;
            }
          }
        }
       return sum;
   }
}
```

Comment: Si con código seria mejor para encontrar el error

Comment: Hola Martín, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento). Como te indica Francisco, deberías incluir el código que genera el error para poder ayudarte (lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información).

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien tu problema está que cuando pasas el argumento al método prod no estás capturando el contenido del arrego de la clase main, te lo marco con una flecha.Espero que te sea de ayuda.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final boolean[] array = { true, false, true, false, true, false, true   };
        System.out.println(prod(array));
    }

public static int prod(final boolean[] args) {
    /*-->*/boolean[] arreglo = args;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; ++i) {
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            if (arreglo[i] == true) {
                sum++;
            }
        } else {
            if (arreglo[i] == false) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

cambia esto:

```
boolean[] arreglo = {};
```

por

```
boolean[] arreglo = args;
```

Saludos!